# Generic Type Mismatch not Causing Typescript Strict Compiler to Fail

Tags: typescript

I expect the following code to fail when compiled using strict mode, however, the code is successfully compiled. The following example is a small reproducable example of larger project I am working on which requires the compiler to fail in such a scenario.

Can I configure the compiler such that this example will cause it fail? Alternative implementations that catch this issue are also welcome.

**Example**

```
type ParcelSize = 'SMALL' | 'MEDIUM' | 'LARGE'

interface ParcelPickupHelper<P extends ParcelSize> {
    pickup(size: P): void
}


interface ParcelDeliveryHelper<P extends ParcelSize> {
    deliver(size: P): void
}

class SmallParcelPickupHelper implements ParcelPickupHelper<'SMALL'> {
    pickup(size: ParcelSize) {
        console.log(size)
    }
}


class LargeParcelDeliveryHelper implements ParcelDeliveryHelper<'LARGE'> {
    deliver(size: ParcelSize) {
        console.log(size)
    }
}


class Courier<P extends ParcelSize> {

    parcelPickupHelper: ParcelPickupHelper<P>
    parcelDeliveryHelper: ParcelDeliveryHelper<P>

    constructor(parcelPickupHelper: ParcelPickupHelper<P>, parcelDeliveryHelper: ParcelDeliveryHelper<P>) {
        this.parcelPickupHelper = parcelPickupHelper
        this.parcelDeliveryHelper = parcelDeliveryHelper
    }
}


const parcelPickupHelper = new SmallParcelPickupHelper()
const parcelDeliveryHelper = new LargeParcelDeliveryHelper()

const courier: Courier<'SMALL'> = new Courier(parcelPickupHelper, parcelDeliveryHelper)
```

**tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true
  },
  "lib": ["es2022"]
}
```

command: `npx tsc`:

- Expected: compiler to fail on line `const courier: Courier<'SMALL'> = new Courier(parcelPickupHelper, parcelDeliveryHelper)`
- Actual: compiles successfully

Comment: @T.J.Crowder apologies for the vagueness. Yes that’s where I expected the code to fail - thanks for your input. Can you spot any deficiencies in this example implementation? Ideally, I would like guaranteed type safety, so I wonder if a different approach can make better use of the structural type system.

Comment: TS method parameters are checked *bivariantly* which is unsafe. If you use function property syntax instead you can get the safer *covariant* checking, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ3k5w). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the comment! Yes, that meets my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should probably make it so that a `SmallParcelPickupHelper` can only `pickup` a `"SMALL"`; your original typing allowed it to `pickup` any `ParcelSize`.  An [`implements` clause](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#implements-clauses) doesn't automatically restrict the class implementation; all it does is *check* the implementation. So if `SmallParcelPickupHelper` can `pickup()` any `ParcelSize`, it will allow things you presumably want to prevent:

```
class SmallParcelPickupHelper implements ParcelPickupHelper<'SMALL'> {
  pickup(size: "SMALL") { // <-- change this
    console.log(size)
  }
}
```

And the same can be said for `LargeParcelDeliveryHelper`:

```
class LargeParcelDeliveryHelper implements ParcelDeliveryHelper<'LARGE'> {
  deliver(size: "LARGE") { // <-- change this
    console.log(size)
  }
}
```

Once you do that, it will still not behave how you want, because [method parameters are always checked *bivariantly*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218)), which allows both the safe widening of function inputs, and the unsafe *narrowing* of them.  The unsafe narrowing is causing things to succeed when you expect them to fail.

Assuming you have [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictFunctionTypes) enabled (or just [`--strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict)), unsafe function parameters are rejected, *but only for non-method functions*.  Methods are still checked bivariantly no matter what.  Luckily, you can change your interfaces to use function-valued property syntax instead of method syntax, and the implementing classes can still use methods to satisfy them:

```
interface ParcelPickupHelper<P extends ParcelSize> {
  pickup: (size: P) => void // looks like a fn-valued property now
}

interface ParcelDeliveryHelper<P extends ParcelSize> {
  deliver: (size: P) => void // looks like a fn-valued property now
}
```

And now, finally, you get the desired error:

```
const courier: Courier<'SMALL'> =
  new Courier(parcelPickupHelper, parcelDeliveryHelper) // error!
// -----------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Argument of type 'LargeParcelDeliveryHelper' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'ParcelDeliveryHelper<"SMALL">'.
// Type '"SMALL"' is not assignable to type '"LARGE"'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJwMYQDYGUCWAvaBeKAcnQFkBBAGQsKgB8iSBRAEQEkBVEm+wisgJQDijQgChRmAHbAICAGZwUsRClQxMSANYBXMAAk0kBAB4YUCAA8ZkgCYBnZcjRZcAPigBvUVChgNOsAAuKAAKOxwIYJgASig8dwA3AHtMG1EAX3EpGXlFaHgnVGY0TATZEANUI1NzKwhbBwLVFwh3Lx8bErKEYLCIqNj4qGTUjPEkVDg7B3QAWzhUNRU0dS1dSqMoTFmwVAhZ+uBG5bV-dcNZY2JyKkI2718zsD7cYIAiUkoKN9j2nygkElJHYknsAHSoJIAcxeEGiD0ymVEEymDgoiChECaaGKqFK5Q2si2Oz2B2kx0KuPxCAqFxMvAEwjungenTx3Vh7z4QkYPxZ-wBQJB4MhMPCuHhPkR4mRk2mUAAwkltAhMJczJZrPZHM0IvcHmATqsAoSejqVk9TaZXAaTlTurSqrIonaugS6dbxD5AcDgAhtEhgEkECFDYVjecnWbsac1voPTBXAAaXyu9nuqMuylumlWxO-B4+YAAC0wdjBYdUEfjUbiqfDlrphagJbLFbT1MdmwIlZxOa7sgRY3GQuA9arjdrBEkEAA7lA5gslg246aQvCfXYx72iv3TXWZ-P0QhMTH7RmjOuR77BSq1WalXfLtcvsy8A9D4rlarZKGjZOjBTHdz1zOlYgAenA8wEAQYMAEJREgqAAFpULQ9CMMwrDkPcAA-fCCMIoiiMQqCyBPbQyTHJI5BbcBoF4DEsQ7B1TRoMsoEkJIx1RTAoUkOAACM9hbJIoFI+s4AOHIoBoujICIM89w9D4bm+VxCDBUQgA)